# Updating Vaadin 14.0.10 app to 14.5.4 results into MIME type error for resources loaded from /VAADIN/

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin 14.0.10 app with Spring Boot and a Spring Security configuration. I'm trying to update it to 14.5.4, but after the update, I get a blank page when I try to load the app. There are no errors on the server logs, but on the browser console, it shows two errors:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

and

```
login:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Looking at the Network tab, it seems that both `webcomponents-loader.js` and `vaadin-bundle-*.cache.js` get status 302 "script/redirect". Both files are served from under `/VAADIN/build`.

At first I thought this could be a Spring Security configuration problem, but in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation, I have:

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                // Vaadin Flow static resources
                "/VAADIN/**",

                // the standard favicon URI
                "/favicon.ico",

                // the robots exclusion standard
                "/robots.txt",
                // and so on
```

...and the `/VAADIN/**` matcher should take care of giving access to the problematic files.

I've tried running mvn clean and I've deleted and repopulated `node_modules` to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was `webpack.generated.js`, which was erroneously stored in the project's Git repository. Deleting the file and rebuilding project fixed the issue. Even though this was a "user error" in a sense, the file should have been automatically overridden in the case of a version upgrade, as the webpack output path has been changed between 14.0 and 14.5: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/10932